# Visual Studio Code change snippet text color

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know what's the code to change the color of snippet text?

show off dark snippet color, which is not readable

[EDIT by Mark: these are "suggestions", not strictly snippet text although snippets may be included in the suggestions.]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"editorSuggestWidget.foreground": "#ff0000",
```

and

```
"editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground": "#ff0000",
```

or you could just change the background by :

```
"editorSuggestWidget.background": "#ff0000",
```

There are a couple of other `editorSuggestWidget` colorCustomizations.

BTW, "snippets" are another unrelated thing altogether.